# Is it possible to create a collection in mongodb as key-value

Tags: mongodb

I am very new to mongodb. Due to lack of time to study mongodb in depth, I'm asking this question.

Is it possible to create a collection in key-value pattern without using _id.

"1", "2", "3" will act as a key instead of _id.

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "X",
        "address": {
            "street": "abc",
            "zip": 12345
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "Y",
        "address": {
            "street": "efg",
            "zip": 12346
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "name": "Z",
        "address": {
            "street": "lmn",
            "zip": 12347
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
Can I say Mongodb's collection is a array?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? If required you can create an attribute as custom_key and keep 1,2,3 or whatever required as value in that.

Comment: Yes, we can do that. But I am exploring the possibilities. Can you please comment on my `EDIT 1`

Comment: you can search with custom key, also have a index on that key.. but mongo will still make an _id

Comment: or you can use _id as your custom key.

Answer (score 1):

After my finding, It seems that Mongodb's collection is a array of documents. So, this is not possible as what I've mentioned in my question.

But I can do something like

```
{ "_id" : "12345", "3" : { "name" : "krishna" } }
{ "_id" : "123" }
```